Why does my kernel not display any character?
there's a problem with my bootloader, the kernel wont put H on the screen
and i also tried to fix my code but it still does not work. Why does it not put H on the screen?
code:
boot.asm:
[org 0x7C00]
bits 16

start:
    cli                     ; Disable interrupts
    xor ax, ax               ; Set segment registers correctly
    mov ds, ax               ; DS should be 0 for 0x0000:7C00 address
    mov es, ax               ; ES to 0 as well
    mov ss, ax               ; SS to 0, but we will adjust the stack pointer
    mov sp, 0x7C00           ; Set stack pointer to top of the bootloader

    ; Set 80x25 text mode (BIOS interrupt)
    mov ax, 0x0003           ; BIOS video service - Set mode 3 (80x25 text mode)
    int 0x10                 ; Call BIOS interrupt to set the mode

    ; Debugging message: Indicate bootloader start
    mov si, msg_start
    call print_string

    call load_kernel         ; Call kernel loading routine

    ; If we reach here, loading the kernel failed
    mov si, msg_load_fail
    call print_string
    jmp $

load_kernel:
    ; Load the kernel from disk (10 sectors starting at sector 2)
    mov bx, 0x1000           ; Address to load the kernel (0x1000)
    mov dh, 0                ; Head number (0, first head)
    mov cx, 0x0002           ; Cylinder 0, sector 2 (start loading from second sector)
    mov ax, 0x0201           ; INT 13h - AH = 0x02 (Read sectors), AL = 1 sector
    ; The DL register already contains the drive number

read_sector:
    int 0x13                 ; BIOS disk read interrupt
    jc disk_error            ; If carry flag is set, there was an error

    add bx, 512              ; Move to the next memory position (advance by 512 bytes for the next sector)
    inc cx                   ; Load next sector
    cmp cx, 0x000C           ; Check if we've loaded 10 sectors (sector 2 to sector 11)
    jl read_sector           ; If we haven't loaded enough, continue loading

    ; Debugging message: Indicate successful kernel loading
    mov si, msg_load_success
    call print_string

    ; Switch to protected mode
    call switch_to_protected_mode

    ; Jump to the kernel (now in protected mode)
    jmp 0x08:0x1000          ; 0x08 is the kernel's code segment, and 0x1000 is where we loaded the kernel

disk_error:
    ; Debugging message: Indicate disk error
    mov si, msg_disk_error
    call print_string
    hlt                      ; Halt the CPU
    jmp disk_error           ; Infinite loop in case of error

switch_to_protected_mode:
    ; Enable A20 line (usually done by the BIOS, so no need here)

    ; Set up GDT
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]     ; Load the GDT descriptor

    ; Set PE (Protection Enable) bit in CR0
    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    ; Far jump to protected mode entry point to flush instruction queue
    jmp 0x08:protected_mode_entry

protected_mode_entry:
    ; Now in protected mode, set up segment registers
    mov ax, 0x10              ; 0x10 is the data segment selector in GDT
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax
    mov fs, ax
    mov gs, ax
    mov ss, ax

    ; Indicate we've successfully switched to protected mode (you can add print logic here)

    ret

print_string:
    ; Print a null-terminated string at DS:SI
    mov ah, 0x0E             ; BIOS teletype function
.next_char:
    lodsb                    ; Load byte at DS:SI into AL and increment SI
    test al, al              ; Check if we reached the null terminator
    jz .done                 ; If zero, we are done
    int 0x10                 ; Print character in AL
    jmp .next_char           ; Repeat for the next character
.done:
    ret

gdt_descriptor:
    dw gdt_end - gdt - 1      ; Size of the GDT
    dd gdt                    ; Address of the GDT

gdt:
    ; Null descriptor
    dd 0x00000000
    dd 0x00000000
    ; Code segment descriptor (base 0, limit 4GB, execute/read)
    dd 0x0000FFFF
    dd 0x00CF9A00
    ; Data segment descriptor (base 0, limit 4GB, read/write)
    dd 0x0000FFFF
    dd 0x00CF9200

gdt_end:

msg_start db 'Bootloader starting...', 0
msg_load_success db 'Kernel loaded successfully.', 0
msg_load_fail db 'Kernel loading failed.', 0
msg_disk_error db 'Disk error occurred!', 0
times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0 ; Pad to 510 bytes to make the bootloader exactly 512 bytes dw 0xAA55 ; Boot signature

I think the problem is in boot.asm.
kernel.c:
void kernel_main() {
    char *video_memory = (char *)0xb8000;  // Pointer to video memory
    video_memory[1] = 0x4F; // Red text on white background
    video_memory[0] = 'H';  // Print 'H' to the screen
    while (1);              // Infinite loop to keep the kernel running
}

linker.ld:
OUTPUT_FORMAT(elf32-i386)
ENTRY(kernel_main)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x1000;  /* Start the kernel at this memory location */

    .text : {
        *(.text)
    }

    .data : {
        *(.data)
    }

    .bss : {
        *(.bss)
    }
}

commands used to make disk img:
clang -target i386-pc-none-elf -ffreestanding -c kernel.c -o kernel.o
ld.lld -T linker.ld -o kernel.bin kernel.o
nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin
dd if=/dev/zero of=disk.img bs=512 count=2880
dd if=boot.bin of=disk.img bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc(this loads the bootloader to sector 1)
dd if=kernel.bin of=disk.img bs=512 seek=2 conv=notrunc(this loads the kernel to sector 2)
qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=disk.img -L "D:\CNQM\QEMU\"

output from QEMU:
Bootloader starting...Kernel loaded successfully.(does not output H)
I tried to debug with gdb but i cant get it to work.
I tried to put a protected mode switch to switch to protected mode only when the kernel is about to load and i tought that would fix it, but it didnt and i tried to put a debugger next but it doesen't work for some reason.

Your kernel.bin is an ELF file not a plain binary. Try OUTPUT_FORMAT(binary) instead. Also note that the ENTRY(kernel_main) will have no effect and you should really make sure your kernel_main will be at the beginning of the section.

As I commented on the staging-ground version of this post (https://stackoverflow.com/staging-ground/79069275), you still have bugs that were pointed out in your first question about this code, like the ELF instead of flat binary which How to make the kernel for my bootloader? shows you how to make.  And getting a working debugger setup is essential, if that's what you mean by "can't get it [GDB] to work".  The debugger built in to Bochs is even better; it always knows what mode the CPU is in so its disassembly should match what single-stepping does.

Also, switch_to_protected_mode shouldn't ret back to 16-bit code.  ret in 32-bit mode will pop a 32-bit return address (but your caller only pushed 16). And even if EIP did end up pointing at jmp 0x08:0x1000, that instruction was encoded for bits 16 mode but the CPU's now in 32-bit mode. (Assuming the code segment in your GDT is 32-bit like it needs to be to run your compiler output.)  Either have protected_mode_entry jump to your kernel, or don't make switch_to_protected_mode a called function at all.  (You need bits 32 for code that will run in 32-bit mode).

The example in How to make the kernel for my bootloader? works correctly, if you want to compare the differences.
